# Checking Multiple Shapes in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, selection, powerpoint, shapes, presentation

thanks in advance.

I have 44 shapes on a slide (B01 - B44) that I want to check to see if they DO NOT contain the letter "A". There are other shapes that I want to exclude from the search. I would like to do this without a bunch of "and"s but I'm somewhat new to VBA.

Something like:

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("B##").TextFrame.TextRange.Text <> "A" Then MsgBox "No A's"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a loop:

```
Dim i as Long, a As Long
Dim shp as Shape
Dim pres as Pres: Set  pres = ActivePresentation

For i = 1 to 44
    Set shp = pres.Slides(2).Shapes("B" & i)
    If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text <> "A" Then
        aCount = aCount+1
    End If
Next

If aCount = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "No A's were found"
Else:
    MsgBox aCount & " A's were found"
End If
```

Note: This checks to see if the text **is** "A", not whether it **contains** the letter "A".

Comment: This worked EXCEPT that I only what the "then" to happen if ALL of the shapes do not have A's. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Much appreciated!

Comment: See my revised answer. This will only tell you *how many*, not which shapes contain them. To do the latter, you will need to use an array, dictionary, or collection.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is working for you, please consider marking this answer as "Accepted".  Cheers.